# Enabling triple/three slash XML comments in Visual Studio 2010 for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My work version of Visual Studio 2010 doesn't seem to generate XML commentary for me while coding in C# and typing ///. Yet, my Visual Studio 2010 at home does this just fine, as does the version of Visual Studio 2008 I have at work.

I have searched for the option to enable these XML comments both locally and online to no avail. Can anyone please tell me where I can toggle whether the /// XML comments are enabled? Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's an option in the **Text Editor** section of **Tools, Options...** called "Generate XML documentation comments for ///".

[image: Generate XML documentation comments for ///]

Comment: Thank you very much! You are my new hero!

Comment: Lots more options in VS 2017, but it's still there, same bat place, same bat name, now under "Editor Help".

Answer (score 15):

Tools → Properties → Text Editor → C# → Advanced.

Tick the checkbox next to `Generate XML documentation comments for ///`.

[image: XML comments config option]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm going to have to give this one to DaveShaw as he was just a split second faster. If it makes you feel better though, you are equally my new hero!

Comment: @Jonk268 - Nothing is stopping you from giving us both upvotes ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I seem to need 15 reputation, otherwise I would happily do so!

Comment: @Jonk268, he's got plenty of Rep don't worry ;).

Comment: If you look at the timestamp you can see that Oded posted his comment 17 seconds *before* DaveShaw. Not sure about what split second you're talking about :)