# How to generate code comment for C# function, class in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I need input /// and then ENTER to generate comment for functions or classes.

Any help?

Comment: I have a Resharper 9 and it works exactly how you have described. I was always sure that it is a Visual Studio built-in feature...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling triple/three slash XML comments in Visual Studio 2010 for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481303/enabling-triple-three-slash-xml-comments-in-visual-studio-2010-for-c-sharp)

Comment: No guys, I mean Visual Studio Code (VSCode). Not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ctrl-K, Ctrl-C to create marks the current line or selected lines of code as a comment, using the correct comment syntax for the programming language.

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Yes, we can use Ctrl + K, Ctrl + C, Ctrl + U for existing lines. But I mean, generate code comment for a function.

Answer (score 1):

If this is still an issue for you guys, there's an extension that helps you with this: C# XML Documentation comments. It can be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.docomment

Typing /// would generate a new comments section.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/c-xml-comments-in-visual-studio-code/), this is a build-in feature of vscode now.

You can enable "Format On Type" by adding this to vscode json config:

```json
"editor.formatOnType": true
```

or search this setting id in the setting ui:

```
editor.formatOnType
```

Then type `///` would add the xml comments.