# XML Auto Commenting C# in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, xml-comments, visual-studio-code

In MonoDevelop, when I type "///", it auto-generates an xml-style comment like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Describes the variable x
/// </summary>
int x = 0;
```

Is there a way to get this behavior in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: By default, looks like that doesn't work for local variables. /// works for method signatures and class properties though. Do you really comment local variables?

Comment: There is no a practical use for this, you can do this in Visual studio with all properties and methods, if it is a local varialbe then just a comment (//) should be enough

Comment: That's weird. For me, it doesn't work for methods or properties. Is there maybe a setting I need to change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481303/enabling-triple-three-slash-xml-comments-in-visual-studio-2010-for-c-sharp

Comment: To be clear: I am using Visual Studio Code(https://code.visualstudio.com/), not the regular visual studio.

Answer (score 92):

Starting with [C# for Visual Studio Code Extension 1.23.8](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.23.8) this is supported when `Editor: Format On Type.` setting is enabled.

Settings can be found in the menu under `File/Preferences/Settings` (Windows/Linux) / `Code/Preferences/Settings` (macOS).

The required setting is available under `Text Editor/Formatting`.

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update - this saved me a bit of time.

Comment: I was looking for this setting under C#. Thank you.

Comment: In Mac it is under Code/Preferences/Settings/Text Editor/Formatting

Answer (score 54):

This feature is not available out-of-the-box with VS Code, but like most features is available via third-party extensions. As of the time of this answer, here is a popular extension that provides some XML comments support to VS Code:

[C# XML Documentation Comments Support for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/k--kato.docomment)

If that extension doesn't work for you, you may be able to find alternatives by searching the [VS Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=xml%20comments&target=VSCode)

Comment: That extension is deprecated as it is built in to the C# for Visual Studio Code extension (see [Pascal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65716253/8804293))

Answer (score 5):

You can set this just for c# if you use Visual Studio Code for other languages as well:

- Open the command palette  and search for *Configure Language Specific Settings*

[image]

- Select C# and search for *Format On Type*

[image]

[Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)