# How to use three slash commenting in Visual Studio Code on OSX?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out how to use the autofill comments whenever you do the three slashes ///. In Monodevelop and Visual Studio it works but not visual studio code.

The results is similar to this:

```
/// <summary>
///     Summary Here
/// </summary>
/// <param name="param1">param1 description</param>
/// <param name="param2">param2 description</param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275209/xml-auto-commenting-c-sharp-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi you can install below extension:

[Visual Studio Marketplace | C# XML Documentation Comment (Keisuke Kato)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.docomment)