# Visual Studio: How would I write tool-tips for my own methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The tool-tips in Visual Studio are very helpful, they can give you a quick clarification of the purpose of a method or class.

I was wondering if I can make my own tool-tips with a short summary of the functionality of my method?

Here is a picture to clarify what I mean.

[Visual Studio ToolTip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANg5s.png)

Comment: XML commnets you mean?

Comment: Just before the first line of your methods (or properties, or classes) type a triple slash (///+Enter) then fill it with description of your method. They are called [XML Comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C# compiler has this feature built in.
Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx to know more about it.

As an example:

```
/// <summary>
///     This is a description.
/// </summary>
public void Do()
{

}
```

Microsoft used to create their msdn documentation website using **Sandcastle**.
They no longer develop the tool but it is **free to use**.
If you want to turn your C# comments into a web documentation you can use Sandcastle to built the website at compile time. Very useful if you design libraries or general open source software.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @slipped_disk You are welcome :) Make sure to use other xml tags too. the summary tag isn't the only one. You can also reference parameters and other types.

Comment: Make sure you have the xml file generation enabled, found in the project properties. If this is turned off other projects wont be able to see the tooltips. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9481353/1363780

Comment: @GER I am pretty sure this only applies if you are referencing the dll directly. Referencing a project from the same solution does not have this constraint as far as I know. But yes, if you deploy a library you should have this option enabled and deploy the xml with the dll.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is known as `summary`. See this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx) post for details. In visual studio, you can type `/` three times above the method/peroperty in order to add its summary. For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the sum of specified params
/// <param name="x">Operand 1</param>
/// <param name="y">Operand 2</param>
/// </summary>
private int GetSum(int x, int y)
{
    //logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are called XML comments.

For example:

```
/// <summary>  
///  This class performs an important function.  
/// </summary>  
public class MyClass{}
```

For more info take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx